# Update jquery scrollbar after ng-repeat render

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scrollbar

Scrollbar don't see height of div because scrollbar update apply before child elements render.
How i can watch what elements is compiled?

I used watch to see when object adding to array. It works fine, but tinyscrollab_update sees empty div, because ng-repeat no compiled yet.

```
$scope.$watch('comments', function(){
    angular.element('#comment-list').tinyscrollbar_update('relative');
});
```

Comment: Do it in directive. Learn more here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @falloff, you should post your solution and accept it as an answer (so that this question no longer appears on the "unanswered" list).

Answer (score 1):

I write it in directive.

```
app.directive('commentsDirective', function(){
   $scope.$watch('comments', function(){
      angular.element('#comment-list').tinyscrollbar_update('relative');
   });
})
```